# Regex pattern for smileys cannot differentiate between minus and range

Tags: java, regex

I am doing this regex

```
[:|;]{1}([\\(|\\)|D|p]|[-\\(]|[-\\)]){1}
```

for this candidate

```
:) :) x-] :ox ;-( ;-) ;~( :~D ;)
```

here
https://regex101.com/r/3swEO2/3/

Expected result is the matching of
:) :) ;-( ;-)

But I cannot create a pattern with the minusses, which are recognized as ranges when not at the beginning of a matcher group.

A hint for correct groups would be appreciated!

Comment: So you need to match colon without hyphen, and semi-colons with hyphen?

Comment: You can use minuses, you just need to escape them with a backslash (or 2, since this is for Java)

Comment: @CinCout colon with or without hyphen and semi-colon only with hyphen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

`(:-?[\|DdPpXx\[\])(]|;-[\|DdPpXx\[\])(])`

`[\|DdPpXx\[\])(]` is the character set which can be used to cover all the possible characters.

Other than that, I am using the OR pipe `|` to cover the two cases wrt to `:` and `;`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3swEO2/6)

Answer (score 2):

Why try to match it in the same group? Just add another part to match with a {0, 1} quantifier.

```
[:|;]{1}\-{0,1}([\(|\)|D|p]){1}
```

Since you are using this in Java, you might need to double the backslashes in order to properly escape the String first.

---

Edit for the comment:

In that case, you can do something like this:

```
:\)|[:|;]{1}\-{1}([\(|\)|D|p]){1}
```

Or since the case doesn't seem to have many possible matches, just enumerate them like this:

```
:\)|;-\(|;-\)
```

---

Edit for comment #2:

I tested it and it works just fine:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = ":) :) x-] :ox ;-( ;-) ;~( :~D ;)";
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(":\\)|;-\\(|;-\\)");
        Matcher m = patt.matcher(s);

        while (m.find())
            System.out.print(m.group() + " ");
    }
}
```

Prints all 4 matches: `:) :) ;-( ;-)`

Comment: I extended my answer to match your requirements better.

Comment: thank you! enumeration does not work. I just need to exclude ;) from the pattern you have given: `[?!;\)]` something like that?

Comment: Tested it out and everything seems to work as expected (added my example to the original answer).